# 商業登記電子証明書でvisualstudioで作成したwindowsアプリケーションへのコードサイニングの方法について

Tags: visual-studio

visual studioでビルドしたインストーラつきのwindowsアプリケーションを配布する際に、コードサイニング証明書を付与しないと、ダウンロードしてインストールする際に警告が出るため、コードサイニング証明書として商業登記電子証明書を使用したいと思いますが、様々な手順を試してみましたがエラーとなります。
やってみたことがあり、成功された方いらっしゃいましたら手順等を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので参考になるかも。[コードサイニング証明書を買う前に](https://www.nda.co.jp/memo/codesigning/index.html), [コード署名用証明書と Visual Studio での署名設定](https://mseeeen.msen.jp/code-signing-certificate/), [個人事業主として EV コードサイニング証明書を取得してみた](https://elleneast.com/?p=6515), [Windowsネイティブアプリにコードサイニング証明書をつける](https://qiita.com/Chitama/items/915abc7b872b1e086800), [Windowsアプリケーションのコードサイニング証明書の選定について教えてください。](https://teratail.com/questions/151177) 最初の記事に商業登記電子証明書でも出来そうなことが書いてありますが、それでも工夫が必要なようです。

Comment: 試した手順の詳細を記載していただいた方が的確な指摘が得られると思います。またエラーの内容も省略せずに記載していただかないと、どこで躓いているのか第三者には伝わりづらいです。

Answer (score 1):

特定の業者を推奨する意図はありませんが、例えば[GLobalSignさんの電子証明書・認証サービス一覧](https://jp.globalsign.com/service/)を見るとわかりますが、電子証明書にはいくつかの種類があり、コードサイニング証明書はそのうちの１種類でしかありません。

そして[商業登記電子証明書を利用することができる手続の例](http://www.moj.go.jp/MINJI/minji06_00028.html#01)にコードサイニングは含まれていません。

コードサイニングを行いたいのであれば、コードサイニング証明書を購入してください。

なお、[開発元を厳格に審査、SmartScreenの警告表示を防止](https://jp.globalsign.com/service/codesign/ev_authenticode.html)と書かれているように、警告抑止が目的の場合、コードサイニング証明書ではダメで、EVコードサイニング証明書を購入する必要があります。